# Cross-platform, queryable, local data storage using HTML5?

Tags: database, html, mobile, cross-platform

I've done quite some research now on HTML5, but I am still left wondering what would be my best guess to implement **local data storage** that is truly **cross-platform** (i.e., runs on all important **mobile** platforms + possibly on desktop), and can easily be **queried**?

I want an **HTML5 web application** (to reach all mobile/(desktop) platforms, and for its independence of third party frameworks/libraries), but using local/offline storage to mimic performance of native applications (and do not necessarily require connectivity). It creates/alters/manages certain records for a user (up to a couple of hundred records per year). Apart from data storage, as the app doesn't need any other access to the device, I think HTML5 would be a good option.

Some *requirements* on the data I want to store:

- the best format would be some **lightweight database** like SQLite (due to performance reasons, and the ability to update single records without having to write a whole file (as in the case of XML))

  - *disadvantage*: I don't see any technology available across all platforms; WebSQL is deprecated, and IndexedDB is not available in too many browsers yet
- the data records shall be easily **exportable/downloadable in XML format** (so that the user can read/modify it on his own)

  - therefore, XML would be a good way to go; I assume the datasize to be reasonably low for this option; 2 concerns though:
  - *disadvantage 1*: I *need a query-language* that allows me to easily select/sort/alter specific records (sthg like XQuery, but available in all browsers and running locally on the client)
  - *disadvantage 2*: as far as I have seen, HTML5 FileWriterAPI support is nowhere near mature - therefore, how would I be able to alter/save the XML data locally on the client? (ok, I have seen examples where the whole XML file is saved as a single key/value pair in local storage; but disadvantage 1 would still apply...)

What options do I have? **Is HTML5 mature enough** to do what I am longing for?

If not, what alternatives would meet my requirements? *Couple of loose thoughts: some third party libraries (JQuery(?), JSON(?) or cross-platform frameworks (a la Phonegap - which I wanted to avoid in the first place, due to their limitations), or use some server-side storage (that is synced with local storage)?*

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what limitations of Phonegap are you talking about, 
I would suggest your application needs to be a hybrid one. 
According to you requirements, you need to use native SQLite in different operating systems. 
For that you need to use Phonegap, where you can write your own plugin, in which javascript act as the interface and the implementation is in native code.

Otherwise you can always check out lawnchair
http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

Thanks
Gaurav Gupta 
Paxcel

Comment: Hi Gaurav, sorry for the late. The limitations I was talking about are mainly the dependence on such third-party frameworks. You have to rely on what APIs they allow to access, and always having to wait until the latest stuff/versions are being supported. Therefore, a HTML5-only solution would have been much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

For others who happened upon this post. I am currently searching for a solution as well and ran into localForage which seems a pretty good choice.

https://github.com/mozilla/localForage